# Use multiple annotations on a method and pass the data

Tags: spring, caching, annotations

I have two annotations on my method :

```
    @Profiled(tag = "XXX") ( // provided by perf4j
    @Cacheable(unless="takesLong")  // provided by spring 
    public String cacheResultsIfTakesLong() {
```

My aim is to cache the results of `cacheResultsIfTakesLong` method only if it takes longer than a specified time to execute. 
Is there a way to pass the execution time, calculated during processing of `@Profiled` annotation, to be used in 'unless' attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any out of the box solution for retrieving method execution time. What you can do though is to pass an additional parameter to the method and update that parameter at the end of the method. This parameter you can use to check whether you need to cache result or not.

```
@Profiled(tag = "XXX") ( // provided by perf4j
@Cacheable(unless="(#timeTaken.get('key') < 1000)")  // provided by spring 
public String cacheResultsIfTakesLong(method_args..., Map timeTaken) {
    long startTime = ...;
    //method logic
    long endTime = ...;
    timeTaken.put("key", endTime - startTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do this with annotations as you need to run the method first to get the timing and then decide for a conditional caching.

Alternatively you can do it without annotation, something like:

```
@Autowired private CacheManager cacheManager;

public String cacheResultsIfTakesLong(String key) {
     String value = cacheManager.getCache("cacheResultsIfTakesLong").get(key);
     if(value == null){
         StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
         value = ... run your query ...
         stopWatch.stop("XXX");
         if(stopWatch.getElapsedTime() > takesLong)
             cacheManager.getCache("cacheResultsIfTakesLong").put(key,value);
     }
     return value;
}
```